# How do I make my iPhone app find my images?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

My app crashes when I do the following in the applicationDidFinishLaunching event in the app delegate:

```
_textures[mytex] = [[Texture2D alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"]];
```

However when I replace `@"a.png"` with

```
@"/Users/MyUserName/Desktop/MyProjectFolder/a.png"
```

everything works fine.  I've experimented with the relative path stuff for the `a.png` resource... but none of it has worked.  How can I fix this?  I'd like to just say `@"a.png"` for all the image resources (esp. since I did this in another app... where I was working directly with sample code).

So what is that magical setting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`+[UIImage imageNamed:]` will look in your app bundle's resources to find the image. If you add an image to Xcode it will be default be added to the resource copy phase of your project. If you want to make sure it is being copied into your app bundle look at the list on the left side of your Xcode editor, under targets you will see your app name there, under that you will see several build phases, so long as `a.png` appears in the "Copy Bundle Resources" phase you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure a.png is imported as a resource into xCode. If you have done that then referencing it as just "a.png" should work.